# So Close - IsErr Function in VBA Not working?

Tags: excel, vba

I am very close to my solution, but I seem to have one roadblock. I've copied the code below. In Summary, I use a VLookup to pull pseudo-formulas from another worksheet, replace a bogus "ZZZ" with a true cell reference, then turn those cell values into a final formula. That all works great, except that the users who input the pseudo formulas are wont to use erroneous formulas, so I need some error checking. First, I need any VLookup values that don't return a result to be renamed. Second, I need any of the final formulas that are invalid (such as missing a parentheses) to be renamed. Here's what I have so far:

```
Public Sub VLookup()

    ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

'Define what our Rows are for the calculations
    Dim NumRecords As Long
    NumRecords = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Dim CellsForFormula As Range
    Set CellsForFormula = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data").Range("G2", "G" & NumRecords)
    Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data").Select

'Now Insert the VLookup
    Dim WSLogic As Worksheet
    Dim WSData As Worksheet
    Set WSData = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data")
    Set WSLogic = Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Logic Statements")

'Write the Vlookup in the cell
    CellsForFormula(1, 1).Formula = _
        "=VLOOKUP('Paste Daily Data'!B2,'Logic Statements'!A:D,4,False)"
'Copy the Vlookup down
    CellsForFormula(1, 1).Copy _
        Destination:=Range(CellsForFormula(2, 1), CellsForFormula(NumRecords - 1, 1))
'Make sure the formulas actually calculate
    Workbooks("POVA Daily Reporter.xlsm").Worksheets("Paste Daily Data").UsedRange.Calculate

'Copy and Paste so we just keep the result of the Vlookup
    CellsForFormula.Copy
    CellsForFormula.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'Now we can replace the "ZZZ" and "zzz" with the cell reference

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim Cell As Variant
    On Error Resume Next

    For Each Cell In CellsForFormula
        If Cell.Value = "#N/A" Then
            Cell.Value = "Bill-to Not in POVA"
        'ElseIf Cell.Formula.IsErr = "=" & Cell.Value Then
            'Cell.Value = "Logic Code Incorrect"
        Else
            Cell.Formula = "=" & Cell.Value
            ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
        End If
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In CellsForFormula
        Call Cell.Replace("ZZZ", Cell.Offset(0, -4).Address)
        Cell.Application.WorksheetFunction = "="
        ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
    Next Cell

    For Each Cell In CellsForFormula
        If Cell.Value = "#N/A" Then
            Cell.Value = "Bill-to Not in POVA"
            ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
        End If
    Next Cell
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Sheet.Calculate

End Sub
```

The problem is those formulas which are invalid - because of the On Error Resume Next, it's just leaving them alone:

```
AND(LEN($C$37)=10,ISNUMBER(VALUE($C$37))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: there is no `ISNUMBER` in VBA. It should be `IsNumeric`. `ISNUMBER` is for worksheet. Also `OERN` should be used with care. It is a good error handling routine but requires a lot of testing for you not to miss relevant errors. I mean, there are errors you don't want ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is `.WorksheetFunction` and not `.Function`.

For example, change this:

```
For Each Cell In CellsForFormula
        If Cell.Value = "#N/A" Then
            Cell.Value = "Bill-to Not in POVA"
        ElseIf Cell.Formula.IsErr = "=" & Cell.Value Then
            'Cell.Value = "Logic Code Incorrect"
        Else
            Cell.Formula = "=" & Cell.Value
            ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
        End If
    Next Cell
```

To this:

```
For Each Cell In CellsForFormula
        If Cell.Value = "#N/A" Then
            Cell.Value = "Bill-to Not in POVA"
        ElseIf Cell.WorksheetFormula.IsErr = "=" & Cell.Value Then
            'Cell.Value = "Logic Code Incorrect"
        Else
            Cell.Formula = "=" & Cell.Value
            ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True
        End If
    Next Cell
```